# Issue when outputting a print message

Tags: python

```
r = 1            
line_students = ("Line", r)
print(line_students)
```

The output I am receiving is ('Line', 1) but I want to print just 'Line 1' 
The reason I am asking this is that it has lead to another problem in my code, seems easy but I cant figure it out.

Comment: Okay, so do you want to use the `line_students` for anything else? Do you need to actually create this string? Or do you only want to display it?

Comment: My code is looping and each time it loops r = r + 1. So in the end I get a code printing Line 1, Line 2, Line 3... so on till the user clicks a button. Creating a string would make it easier but I am open to suggestions and I can try and implement it into my code.

Comment: Okay, so... what's the problem with just doing `print("Line", r)`?

Comment: `line_students` is a tuple thus if you that you will get a tuple

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `print(*line_students)` .

It will unpack the tuple and print each element joined with space.

The more pythonic way though, would be a `print(f"Line {r}")`

Comment: Thanks mate, appreciate it